# Is there an analytic solution of this Burger's type equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, hyperbolic-pde

I came across the following PDE:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} -f(x,t)\bigg{(}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\bigg{)}= 0$$
for $t > 0$ subject to the initial condition $f(x,0) \equiv f_{0}(x) = \frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}$. This looks like a Burger's equation, apart from the minus sign which in the latter is a plus sign. Is there an analytic solution of this problem?

I tried the method of characteristics. Parametrizing $x$ by $t$, one gets $x = x(t)$ with $x_{0} = x(0)$, the characteristic equation becomes:
$$x(t) = x_{0}-\frac{2x_{0}t}{1-x_{0}^{2}}$$
and I should be able to invert $x_{0} = x_{0}(x,t)$ so to get the solution $f(x,t) = f_{0}(x_{0}(x,t))$, but I was not able to find a solution of the above equation. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Up to $f\mapsto -f$ it is Burger's equation. To solve for $x_0(x,t)$ you need to solve a [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation). Looks a little bit like homework. :-/

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I tried solving the cubic equation. However, the equation has all factors $a,b,c$ and $d$ (as in $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$) and it seems impossible to solve it. One could think about at least getting an existence condition from this equation, but even this seems unlikely.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're having problems using the cubic formula, then this is not a research level question and MathOverflow is not the right forum for it. I've voted to close.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I arrived at this cubic formula after trying to apply the method of characteristics, but there might be another easier way to do it which avoids solving cubic equations. Also, cubic equations are not easy to handle and sometimes only solvable numerically. My question specifically asks whether it is possible to find an analytic solution somehow.